# Nesting blockquotes in QTextEdit window is not shown similar as in HTML

Tags: html, qt, qtextedit

I am trying to show some nested HTML blockquotes in a Qt QTextEdit. The HTML is:

```
<blockquote> I
    <blockquote> Want
        <blockquote> To
            <blockquote> Build
                <blockquote> A
                </blockquote> Great
            </blockquote>Pyramide
        </blockquote> For
    </blockquote> You
</blockquote>
```

It is shown as I intended when opened as HTML:

```
    I
        Want
            To
                Build
                        A
                Great
            Pyramide
        For
    You
```

but in the QTextEdit I get:

```
    I
        Want
            To
                Build
                        A
Great
Pyramide
For
You
```

I know that QTextEdit only support a subset of HTML so that might be it, but I doubt it.

Comment: Why do you doubt it? Qt html subset is really quite limited. It seems that `blockquote` tags are transformed to `p` tags while processing (you can see it in Qt Designer's rich text editor). And `p` tags can't be nested, so when another paragraph starts, previous one ends.

Comment: I just assumed since it seemed to be a basic thing, but I was just guessing =) I will check to see if it is transformed to p tag and find a different work around if that is the case. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: You can use `p` tags with `margin-left` css property, but you need to create separate `p` for each text block with different margin.